# Firebase query by time range [android]

Tags: android, time, firebase

I need to look for the subject that matches the current time. For example, current time is 1:30. So if I'll run a query with Firebase, it should return the subject Math.

Here's my JSON where "2012123458" is a faculty_id.

```
schedule:{
     "2012123458" : {
  "Saturday" : {
    "-K8j0EkwmWjj3vMqB2d3" : {
      "classroom" : "Lab 3",
      "subject" : "Science",
      "time_end" : "2:00",
      "time_start" : "0:00"
    },
    "asdasdasd" : {
      "classroom" : "Lab 6",
      "subject" : "PE",
      "time_end" : "18:00",
      "time_start" : "17:00"
    },
    "qweqweqweqwe" : {
      "classroom" : "Lab 5",
      "subject" : "PE",
      "time_end" : "11:00",
      "time_start" : "9:00"
    }
  }
}
}
```

I've tried this but returns a NullPointerException

```
       gridView.setAdapter(listFaculty);
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            FacultyList faculty = (FacultyList) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String faculty_id = faculty.getID();


            //Display schedule in a Dialog box
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Faculty.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_sched);


           Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://infotrack.firebaseio.com/schedule/"+faculty_id+"/Saturday");
           ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
               @Override
               public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                   for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){


                       schedule sched = postSnapshot.getValue(schedule.class);
                       TextView subject = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtSubject);
                       TextView time = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtTime);
                       TextView classroom = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtClassroom);

                       if(sched != null) {


                           if (checkTime(sched.getTime_start(), sched.getTime_end())){
                               Log.e("test", "x");

                                   Log.e("test", "" + dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());

                                   Log.e("test", postSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                                   Log.e("test", "0");

                                   subject.setText(sched.getSubject());
                                   Log.e("test", sched.getSubject());


                                   time.setText(sched.getTime_start() + " - " + sched.getTime_end());
                                   Log.e("test", "2");


                                   classroom.setText(sched.getClassroom());
                               }

                        }  
                       else { 
                           Log.e("test", "null");
                       }

                   }
               }

               @Override
               public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                   Log.d("sched", firebaseError.getMessage());
               }
           });
           dialog.show();



       }
   });
```

schedule class:

```
public class schedule {

  private String subject;
  private String time_end;
  private String time_start;

  public schedule(){ }

  public schedule(String subject, String time_end, String time_start){

    this.subject = subject;
    this.time_end = time_end;
    this.time_start = time_start;

  }

  public String getSubject(){
    return subject;
  }

  public String getTime_end(){
    return time_end;
  }

  public String getTime_start(){
    return time_start;
  }
}
```

UPDATE: 
The problem now is it does not work for some items on the grid view. It brings me back to my app's home screen after clicking on them. An empty dialog box appears for a short period then returns to the home screen.

Comment: Which exact line throws the `NullPointerException`? What does the `schedule` class look like?

Comment: The exception is thrown here: if(checkTime(sched.getTime_start(), sched.getTime_end())). I'll update my post with the schedule class

Comment: Aha.. in that case, put `if (sched != null)` around it.

Comment: It seems very likely that you're listening to a different location than you expect, one that doesn't have any value. For example, your sample JSON doesn't have `Saturday` in the path, but you're setting up a ref to a path that includes that. When you listen for a location that doesn't have a value, Firebase will call `onDataChange()` with a null snapshot.

Comment: I made sure I added a Saturday child, sorry for not including it on my sample JSON. I updated my code as you suggested. It works for some but not all and it doesn't return an error. It brings me back to my app's home screen. Let me post my real code so you can help me further. Thanks

Comment: I'm not really looking for your complete app. Reduce the problem back to the minimal code+data that reproduces the problem. With that we can help figure what's going on, without spending time on things that are not related to the problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Problem solved! I added an else statement that will return false in my checkTime() method. Thanks for the help and quick responses